# How to receive Broadcast for a certain location

Tags: android, google-play, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-location

I just want to know- is there any way to receive a broadcast for a certain location? Suppose, I have saved a place for alarm and when reach that place I want my app to notify me. For that purpose- how can I use a broadcast receiver?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are looking for is called *geofencing*, and there is a complete guide on the official [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) site on how to implement it using Google Play Services.

Comment: Sorry for such a stupid question. I should have searched more. Anyway, Thanks for your quick response.